# Why "hide" the virtual method in the base class by using the new keyword, not "expose"

Tags: c#, polymorphism, new-operator, overriding, method-hiding

From [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(VS.80).aspx)

> "If the method in the derived class is preceded with the new keyword, the method is defined as being independent of the method in the base class."
>
> "The derived class can then override the base virtual method by using the override keyword or hide the virtual method in the base class by using the new keyword."

Why "hide" the virtual method in the base class by using the new keyword, not "expose"? Doesn't "hide" mean will-not-be-used? The result shows that virtual method is used ('exposed' not 'hidden') in base class when new keyword is used in derived class.

Comment: If you attempt to call the method by name, the "new" method will be selected by the compiler. In other words, the inherited method is effectively hidden behind the "new" method, in that it is not *directly* accessible anymore (but it is accessible indirectly, e.g. through upcasting).